# Solve an equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n$ be unknowns. Let $C=(c_{ij})_{n \times n}$ be an invertible matrix. Suppose that $\sum_{\beta=1}^{n} \mu_{\beta} c_{\alpha, \beta}=\pi i$. I think that we can solve this equation by multiply $C^{-1}$ on both sides of the equation. It is said that the solution is $\mu_{\beta} = i \pi \sum_{\alpha=1}^n c_{\beta, \alpha}^{-1}$. But the solution I get is much more complicated.

Comment: Perhaps there is a confusion between $[C^{-1}]_{ij}$ and $[C_{ij}^{-1}]$.

Comment: @anon, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $\mu_b:=i\pi\sum_{a=1}^nc_{b,a}^{—1}$, we have 
$$\sum_{b=1}^n\mu_bc_{a,b}=\sum_{b=1}^n\sum_{a=1}^ni\pi c_{b,a}^{—1}c_{a,b}=\sum_{b=1}^ni\pi (CC^{—1})_{bb}=ni\pi,$$
so we actually have to take $\mu_b:=\frac 1ni\pi\sum_{a=1}^nc_{b,a}^{—1}$.

The fact you get a more complicated expression could be explained by the expression of the entries of the inverse matrix.